# How to install django non-rel for 1.6.1

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel, non-relational-database

I am using django version 1.6.1,python 2.7.5, and working with mongodb 2.4.6.So all i need is to set mongo engine in django settings file.For this i have to install django non-rel package.but i found only non-rel for django 1.5.How can i install djnago non-rel for 1.6.1

I found this link for django non-rel 1.5

http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Django non-rel is a fork of django, that supports non relational backends. Looking at their github it doesn't look like they have a stable 1.6 release

https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tree/nonrel-1.6-beta

**Update**

There's now a stable branch for Django 1.6 available
https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tree/nonrel-1.6

Comment: django non-rel 1.6 is now stable.